# Call sub on class property change?

Tags: vb.net, class, events, properties, event-handling

I have a custom class which is based off of a TreeNode and this has an Enum property on it called status, setup as shown below.

```
Public _staus As enumStatus

Public Enum enumStatus
   None
   Yes
   No
End Enum
```

Basically when I change this property I want to call a sub routine which just changes the text colour of the item - this sub is contained in the class and is simply a select case statement updating the Me.ForeColor property.

This works correctly if I class myClass.ChangeColourBasedOnStatus but how can I make it automatically do this when a property is changed.

I've tried looking at event handlers but I just can't find an explanation that I understand and can get to work.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: `_staus` (sic) is actually a field, not a `Property`.  I'd add a StatusChanged event and let something (the form perhaps) react to it.  Raise the event in the property setter

Comment: Hi, I thought something like this was coming, can you explain how would I go about doing this?

Comment: [Events in VB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172877.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the field private and add a Property to access it. In the example below I assume that you are using text from a control, but you could modify it to use the enum or other types.

```
Private _staus As enumStatus

Public Enum enumStatus
    None
    Yes
    No
End Enum

Public Property Status As enumStatus
    Get
        Return _staus
    End Get
    Set(value As enumStatus)
        _staus = value
        ChangeColor(TextBox1.Text)
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub ChangeColor(SomeText As String)
    Select Case SomeText
        Case "" : Me.ForeColor = Color.Black
        Case "Stop" : Me.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Case "Go" : Me.ForeColor = Color.Green
    End Select
End Sub
```